# R textplot() -- "col.data" is not a graphical parameter

Tags: r, plot

R version: 3.0.2 (2013-09-25) / platform: x86_64-pc-linux-gnu / package: gplots

I want to do the following:

```
textplot(textVec,col.data="red")
```

`textVec` is a vector of strings (like for ex. `textVec = c("one","two")`)

Then I get the following error:

```
1: In text.default(x = xpos, y = ypos, labels = object, adj = c(0,  ... :
"col.data" is not a graphical parameter
```

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: `textplot` from which package? `wordcloud`, `gplots`...

Comment: Thanks Victorp, forgot that. It's from gplots

Answer (score 2):

If you look at the help for textplot

```
?textplot
```

You'll see that `col.data` only applies when the first argument is a matrix

```
 ## S3 method for class 'matrix'
 textplot(object, halign = c("center", "left", "right"),
          valign = c("center", "top", "bottom"), cex, cmar = 2,
          rmar = 0.5, show.rownames = TRUE, show.colnames = TRUE,
          hadj = 1, vadj = 1, mar = c(1, 1, 4, 1) + 0.1,
          col.data = par("col"), col.rownames = par("col"), 
          col.colnames = par("col"), ...)
```

For a vector of strings you should use

```
textplot(textVec, col="red")
```

(source: `text.default`'s help page )

Comment: Thanks! I am still a bit puzzled: How would I proceed if I want every string in a different color?

Comment: Here's one way: `textplot(matrix(textVec, nrow=2, ncol=1), col.data=matrix(c("red", "blue"), nrow=2, ncol=1), show.rownames=F, show.colnames=F)`.

Comment: Thanks! This comes really close to what I want! Strangely, the strings are aligned at the right, but I added `halign=left` and they are also stacked with a slight shift vertically down. Do you also have an idea how to solve this?

Comment: It seems `halign` refers to the alignment of the matrix as a whole, not the individual cells. `hadj=0` would be what you need, but it breaks the matrix alignment. You might need to choose another library, or manually plot each word with `text` (which is what this library does anyway).